# How to restart compiled php-fpm on 127.0.0.1:9000

Tags: php, linux, compilation

I have the php 5.3.10 on my ubuntu.
Now I installed the 5.5.7 and would like to restart it but when doing:

```
sudo  service php5-fpm restart
```

It restarts the php 5.3.10, not the 5.7.7

By doing :

```
/usr/local/php5.5.7/sbin/php-fpm restart
```

I am getting:

```
Usage: php-fpm [-n] [-e] [-h] [-i] [-m] [-v] [-t] [-p <prefix>] [-g <pid>] [-c <file>] [-d foo[=bar]] [-y <file>] [-D] [-F]
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -v               Version number
  -p, --prefix <dir>
               Specify alternative prefix path to FastCGI process manager (default: /usr/local/php5.5.7).
  -g, --pid <file>
               Specify the PID file location.
  -y, --fpm-config <file>
               Specify alternative path to FastCGI process manager config file.
  -t, --test       Test FPM configuration and exit
  -D, --daemonize  force to run in background, and ignore daemonize option from config file
  -F, --nodaemonize
               force to stay in foreground, and ignore daemonize option from config file
  -R, --allow-to-run-as-root
               Allow pool to run as root (disabled by default)
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify thet using the service php5-fpm restart is restarting the old php 5.3.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with use of service

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify thet using the service php5-fpm restart is restarting the old php 5.3.10